# how is this possible

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I evaluated the Fourier series for $e^{-ax}$   , where $ -\pi \le x \le \pi$, which comes out be what is the first equation in picture tagged with this post below now what I am expected to do is to find the equation for:
 $${\cfrac{\pi}{sinh\;\pi}}$$

[image]

to do that it is made to deduct using $a = 1$ and $x = 0$, my question is why did not we use other combinations like:

$a = 0, x= 0$
$ a = 0, x=1$
as these combinations also make
 $e^{-ax}=1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your problem says $$e^{-ax} = \frac{2\sinh(a\pi)}{\pi}\sum_n\left(c_n\cos(nx) - d_n\sin(nx)\right)$$ Now to get $$\frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi)}$$ you have to choose the right coefficients: first  $a$ has to be $1$ so that $$\sinh(a\pi) = \sinh(\pi)$$ also it cannot be zero due to the fact that the first element of the cosine expansion is $\frac{1}{2a}$ that is not defined in zero.

Choosing $x=0$ is just so that the $\sin(nx)$ expansion is cancelled and $e^{-ax}=1$,  simplifying the expression even more.

Comment: I want to add that you could have used pretty much every $x$ you wanted for the fact that $e^x$, $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ are defined $\forall x$, but obviously the value of $x=0$ gives the easiest expansion for $\frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi)}$